# Python Pillow Issue Pasting RGBA Image on Top of a Filtered Image Causes the Blur to be Lost

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

What I'm trying to do is blur the current canvas/image and then put a menu on top of this with some transparency.

Basically, I have a canvas (RGBA) with existing image drawn on it which I want to blur and use as a background for a menu that I display on top.

Initial Image('canvas' in the code):
[image]

```
    # Use gradient image for background 
    canvas = Image.open(background_image)        
    
    # Create drawing object
    gauges = Image.new("RGBA", size)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(gauges)

    # Do all of the gauge drawings, etc

    blurred = canvas.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(20))

    # Create drawing object
    menu_object_canvas = Image.new("RGBA", size)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(menu_object_canvas)

    # do all of the drawing on the menu_object_canvas 
    
    blurred.paste(menu_object_canvas, position)
```

And when I paste the 'menu_object_canvas', you can see that the original canvas shows through in the alpha areas without the filter.

[image]

How can I achieve what I want, which is to maintain the blurred background with the menu pasted on top?

(BTW - If you are wondering, I'm creating a new touchscreen dashboard for the PiFire project here (https://github.com/nebhead/pifire)

(Edit: Added more example code)

Comment: How exactly was `menu_object_canvas` created?  I'm going to have to guess that it somehow includes the unblurred portions of the original background, and those parts are overwriting `blurred`.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a proper [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to add some more code to help illustrate what I'm doing.  I may just create a basic program here to make it simpler.  Hopefully the above helps.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to go ahead and close this one for now.  I'm trying to reproduce with a very basic stand-alone program and I can't seem to repro the issue.  I think it may be an issue on my side.  I'm going to do more debugging on my own and may re-open if needed.